# php preg replace include slash(/)

Tags: php, regex, regexp-replace

i use preg replace since my column database does not support "strange letters"
but after regex i need keep "/", in this code bellow "/" is always missing
in code bellow i need to get all letter complete

```
<?php
$jurnalName = "TL 110/90-12 K93-N02 AHM+";
$name = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($jurnalName));
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9|\-  +]/', '', $name);

var_dump($name);
```

the result is always "TL 11090-12 K93-N02 AHM+" what i expecting is complete "TL 110/90-12 K93-N02 AHM+"

Comment: You need to add `/` to your list of characters not to remove.

Comment: `/[^A-Za-z0-9|\-  +\/]/`

Comment: You shouldn't call  both`htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`. They both do almost the same thing, so you'll end up encoding the characters twice.

Comment: Also, your `preg_replace()` will end up removing the special characters that are used in HTML entities, e.g. `&amp;` will become `amp`. You should call `htmlentities()` *after* you do the replacement. Although it's not really needed, since you're removing all characters that need to be encoded.

Comment: It's also not usually appropriate to do HTML encoding when you're saving to the database. You should do it when you're displaying results in the web page.

Comment: oh thank very much, i use /[^A-Za-z0-9|\-  +\/]/ and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add / to the list of chars you want to keep

```
<?php
$jurnalName = "TL 110/90-12 K93-N02 AHM+";
$name = htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($jurnalName));
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9|\-\s\+\/]/', '', $name);

var_dump($name);
```

(I also changed the space for \s and scaped the plus +, its optional here but I think its a good practice for characters that have spetial meaning inside regex

Comment: Most characters don't have special meaning inside `[]`. It's usually considered overkill to escape them.